# how to create String array dyanamically

Tags: c#, string

I have following string s

string -1> Ferocactus_glaugescens__0000_009843_007280.jpg

string -2> Sanseveria_zeylanica_0000_009568_007476.jpg

string -3> Schefflera_arb_Gold_Capella__0000_008329_007482.jpg

i want create string array of count equals to no of "_" in string .
eg:

string -1> contains 5 "_" so my string array will like
string []stringArray=new string[5];

string -2> contains 4 "_" so my string array will like
string []stringArray=new string[4];

string -3> contains 7 "_" so my string array will like
string []stringArray=new string[7];

how do i check no of "_"  in given string .

I can check it using for loop and 
i want other simple solution like linq or linq.

Thanks Pramod

Answer (score 4):

```
int no_of_string = s.Split('_').Length;
String[] string = new String[no_of_string];
```

Comment: Good solution but the simple arrays use "Length" property for array size instead of count method.

Comment: @Dubas : Really thanks ! This is mix up with javaScript I am working on write now.

Comment: @infoSetu : there is no count() method on an array ;)

    int nb = s.Split('_').GetLength(0) - 1;

Answer (score 2):

String is an IEnumerable of char, you can do something like:

```
myString.Where(c => c == '_').Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Int32 delimiterCount = " Ferocactus_glaugescens__0000_009843_007280.jpg".Split('_').Length;
```